# connect to sql server to sqlite in sqlite manager

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, sqlitemanager

how do I import a sql query into a sqlite database? I'm using the sqlite manager add on in firefox, and there is an option to import SQL, but I don't see where I can connect to a server. I'm looking for some code in this format:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
Server=servername;Database=dbname; User_Id=username;
Password=password;

SELECT * from table_name;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: One method would be to export the sqlserver query as a delimited text file containing the result set. You can then import it into a sqlite database file using the 'sqlite' command line application.

Comment: thanks Jay. That's obviously a viable alternative. Is there no way to pull sql server directly from sqlite??

Answer (score 0):

Try .read file-1
where in file-1 are the sql-statements exported from your server

Alternative .import file-2 table-1
file-2 an excel-formatted textfile
table-1 will be automatically created if column names are provided in 1st line

Ref: 
https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html
See also: 
http://igrali.com/2015/05/01/using-sqlite-in-windows-10-universal-apps/